# Database not being found... iOS/SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I working on an app that takes input from a text field and puts it into a string. I have a table with a field in it that I want to check the value of the string from the input against the value in the field in the database. I'm new to iOS and fairly new to SQLite.

Code:

```
-(IBAction)setInput:(id)sender
{
NSString *strStoreNumber;
NSString *strRegNumber;

strStoreNumber = StoreNumber.text;
strRegNumber = RegNumber.text;
lblStoreNumber.text = strStoreNumber;
lblRegNumber.text = strRegNumber;

NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
//    NSString* databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tblStore.sqlite"];
NSString* databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tblStore" ofType:@"sqlite"];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    NSLog(@"Opened sqlite database at %@", databasePath);

    //...stuff
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database at %@ with error %s", databasePath, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close (database);
}

NSString *querystring;

// create your statement
querystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT strStore FROM tblStore WHERE strStore = %@;", strStoreNumber];  

const char *sql = [querystring UTF8String];

NSString *szStore = nil;
NSString *szReg = nil;


if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &databasePath, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK) //queryString = Statement
{
    NSLog(@"sql problem occured with: %s", sql);
    NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
else
{
    // you could handle multiple rows here

    while (sqlite3_step(databasePath) == SQLITE_ROW) // queryString = statement
    {            
        szStore = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(databasePath, 0)];
        szReg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(databasePath, 1)];
    } // while        

}

sqlite3_finalize(databasePath);

// Do something with data...  
}
```

It gets to the line "NSLog(@"Opened sqlite database at %@", databasePath);", so it appears as though it has access to the database.  However, when I run the app, I get the "NSLog(@"sql problem occured with: %s", sql);" error, which I can see in the console.  Additionally, in the console, it says "No such table:  tblStore".

I created the table using the Firefox add-on SQLite Manager.  I added the sqlite3 library to the project.  I dragged and dropped the database table I created in SQLite manager into my project, above my two AppDelegate files and my two ViewController files.

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I have properly added the file to the project, and it appears as though the table is found now.  Now I have some strange warnings, though:

"Incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'sqlite3_stmt *' (aka 'struct sqlite3_stmt *')"

This warning appears on the following lines of code:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &databasePath, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)

while (sqlite3_step(sql) == SQLITE_ROW)

szStore = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(sql, 0)];

szReg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(sql, 1)];

sqlite3_finalize(sql);
```

It's got something to do with "sql", but I'm unsure of what.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer, but might be worth considering Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not my choice to use CoreData.  I've been instructed to use SQLite.  Thanks!

Comment: Alright, was just curious since Core Data is pretty damn great :) It does allow you to import sqlite databases by the way. Good luck.

Comment: Who told you to add the ";" at the end of the select statement? Can you show the real nslog output instead of just the format string?

Comment: The console spits out:  2012-05-04 13:54:49.496 CCoDBTry[23306:f803] Opened sqlite database at /Users/MattHeld/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/5DB7A218-A0F6-485F-B366-91FD2F9BC062/Documents/tblStore.sqlite
2012-05-04 13:54:49.499 CCoDBTry[23306:f803] sql problem occured with: SELECT strStore FROM tblStore WHERE strStore = 8053;
2012-05-04 13:54:49.500 CCoDBTry[23306:f803] no such table: tblStore
(lldb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems ok - did you copy the db to the ressource folder of your project?

**EDIT**

Make sure you access your db file with something like that:

```
    - (void) initializeDB {

        // Get the database from the application bundle
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tblStore" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Opening Database"); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Call close to properly clean up
            sqlite3_close(database);

            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to open database: '%s'.", 
                      sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

}
```

Comment: Interesting that you ask that.  I used to notice a resources folder a few months ago (4-5 months) but since updating Xcode, I no longer see a resources folder.  I dragged and dropped the existing table (which I created outside of Xcode, using the Firefox add-on SQLite Manager) and dropped it in my main folder, which includes my .xib, ViewController.h, ViewController.m, AppDelegate.h, and AppDelegate.m

Comment: Sorry I was checking on my project which contains a ressource folder but that's basically a folder I created myself. You can put the db wherever you want in the project. Just make sure that when clicking on your project under build phases / copy bundle ressources your file has been added automaticaly

Comment: When I look at my project folder through Finder, I see my tblStore.sqlite in my project folder.  I do not see the tblStore.sqlite folder in Xcode when I look under build phases>copy bundle.  Is this where I might be running into trouble?  Should I add the tblStore.sqlite file in copy bundle?  Thanks for the replies and the help!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Also, I edited my original code and added your line "NSString* databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tblStore" ofType:@"sqlite"];" AS WELL as removing "//    NSString* databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tblStore.sqlite"];"

Comment: Yes just drag and drop your file from Finder to XCode and have the Add  to targets option selected you should see the file then in XCode and under copy bundle.

Comment: Perfect.  It looks like it can see the table now.  I do have many warnings now, though.  I'll edit my original post and place a comment up there with the warnings.  Thanks for much for the help!  Very High Quality.

Answer (score 1):

The database file you add to the project will be embedded in the main `NSBundle` (see `[NSBundle mainBundle]`).

In order to do what you want, you need to copy the database from the main bundle to the documents folder before trying to access it. Otherwise, as you are experiencing, you will not be able to find the SQLite DB on the document's folder.

Comment: You will have to excuse my ignorance as I am quite new to iOS.  Would you mind providing steps as to how I can accomplish this?  Or at least provide soe sort of resource/tutorial that I could follow?  Thanks!

Comment: I was able to add the file to the bundle by adding it through build phases>copy bundle resources.  Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your database, click finder and write this address(/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/) in finder click ok.
You will get documentary path. 
Open your project document file and paste your database....